# My output shows Value Error: I/O operation on closed file. python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, io, output

I know there are many question regarding the same issue, but i did not find an answer that solve my issue

im  making an app to write certain words on host file, but when i come to output the program, it show that closed file
here is my code

```
import time
from datetime import datetime as dt


host_temp = r"C:\Users\ALAA\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.38.2\hello\web site blocker\hosts"
host_path = r"C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts"
redirect = "127.0.0.1"
website_list = ["www.facebook.com","www.instagram.com", "www.youtube.com"]


while True:
    if dt(dt.now().year,dt.now().month,dt.now().day,16) < dt.now() < dt(dt.now().year,dt.now().month,dt.now().day,23):
        print("Working hours!!!")
        with open(host_temp, "r+") as file:
            content = file.read()
        for website in website_list:
            if website in content:
                pass
            else:
                file.write(redirect + " " + website + "\n")
    else:
        print("Fun hours!!!")
    time.sleep(5)
```

and here the error massage

```
Working hours!!!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ALAA\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.38.2\hello\web site blocker\web_site_blocker.py", line 20, in <module>
    file.write(redirect + " " + website + "\n")
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.
```

Comment: `for website in website_list:` this line is not indented. Is that intentional?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import time
from datetime import datetime as dt


host_temp = r"C:\Users\ALAA\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.38.2\hello\web site blocker\hosts"
host_path = r"C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts"
redirect = "127.0.0.1"
website_list = ["www.facebook.com","www.instagram.com", "www.youtube.com"]


while True:
    if dt(dt.now().year,dt.now().month,dt.now().day,16) < dt.now() < dt(dt.now().year,dt.now().month,dt.now().day,23):
        print("Working hours!!!")
        with open(host_temp, "r+") as file:
            content = file.read()
            for website in website_list:
                if website in content:
                    pass
                else:
                    file.write(redirect + " " + website + "\n")
    else:
        print("Fun hours!!!")
    time.sleep(5)
```

I indented the for loop and its contents since python does not ignore improper indentation

Comment: Awesome! :) Be sure to mark this answer if it really did end up fixing your problem